# Custom *metric* parameter for matrix in unsupervised clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan

Multiple unsupervised algorithms in scikit-learn have two parameters: `affinity` and `metric`, which can take a `precomputed` matrix for affinity and distance matrix respectively.

AffinityPropagation, AgglomerativeClustering, FeatureAgglomeration, and SpectralClustering take `affinity` for `precomputed` matrix
where as
DBSCAN and OPTICS take `metric` for `precomputed` matrix.

I have a two part question:

1. Is it possible to write a custom function that can be used for all of above mentioned six methods?
2. If not, then I want to have a custom function that will be 'callable' for `metric` parameter in DBSCAN and OPTICS (both methods use distance matrix).

From the documentation, I understand that

> it (metric) must be one of the options allowed by `sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances` for its metric parameter.

So is it possible to define a custom function (in DBSCAN and OPTICS) and overwrite one of the preexisting `sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances` function or I have to use `precomputed` in parameters?

Answer (score 0):

**Your first question**:
You should not use the same function for both `affinity` and `metric`, since they mean two different things: the larger the affinity, the nearer the two points, while the larger the metric, the farther away the two points.

**Your second question**:
The parameter `metric` of both `DBSCAN` and `OPTICS` can be a custom function, taking two vectors and returning their difference. From the documentation of [`sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html)

> Alternatively, if `metric` is a callable function, it is called on each
> pair of instances (rows) and the resulting value recorded.

So, yes, you can provide a custom function for the parameter `metric` of `DBSCAN` and `OPTICS`.